# Handling array value in PHP and dumping data to DB

Tags: php, html, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this.

```
    Array
    (
        [book_name] => 342
        [book_title] => Book1
        [myselect] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
                [2] => 3
                [3] => 4
                [4] => 5
            )

    )
```

This needs to get stored in db like this. There are three fields in database table.

```
    book_name       book_title      value
    342             Book1           1
    342             Book1           2
    342             Book1           3
    342             Book1           4
    342             Book1           5
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks,
Kimz

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Start by writing some php code, then test it, and if it doesn't work, find out why, and fix. Repeat until done.

Comment: I agree with @Clive but would change his comment ever so slightly: *Start by writing some php code, then test it, and if it doesn't work,* Ask a question here *and fix. Repeat until done.*

Comment: @Fluffeh *Start by writing some PHP code, then test it, if it doesn't work, debug it, if you get stuck debugging, research on the internet, if you get stuck researching on the internet, take a walk and brew some coffee, debug again, if you're still stuck: consider asking a very specific question on SO.*

Comment: @deceze Yeah, re-reading what I wrote makes it sound like come here with anything - which was not my intention :)

Comment: lol @deceze Impossible

Comment: i have not tried and don't even have an idea to do this. i'm having minmial knowledge in php and with my query/question, I guess someone will help and i got help too !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $arr = array(
    'book_name' => 342,
    'book_title' => 'Book1',
    'myselect' => array(
        '0' => 1,
        '1' => 2,
        '2' => 3,
        '3' => 4,
        '4' => 5
    )

);
 $arrInsrt = array();
foreach ($arr['myselect'] as $key => $value) {
    $arrInsrt[$key]['book_name'] = $arr['book_name'];
    $arrInsrt[$key]['book_title'] = $arr['book_title'];
    $arrInsrt[$key]['value']    = $value;
    //Insert $arrInsrt[$key] here
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrInsrt);
```

Comment: Not sure why there's a downvote here http://codepad.viper-7.com/9FtQme

Comment: I am also not sure why is the down vote.Can you explain Mr.Downvotter.

Comment: @asprin - yup, i said very well, that I'm new to this coding stuff and i don't have any idea in doing this. So getting help here. Don't know what is bothering them. Anyway this code is really superb !!!

Comment: @웃웃웃웃웃 - simply superb. this is what i want. 3 people down-voted me. Don't know why ;(

Comment: @user3350885 What's bothering us is that you're trying to use this site as a free code writing service. That gets the people who volunteer their time here, for free, 's backs up. The answer will have been downvoted because it's encouraging this behaviour that we don't want to see here.

Comment: okies. got it. will consider this again in my next question before I ask.

Comment: @user3350885 A small code sample, representing what you've already tried (even if it's hopelessly wrong), will ward off those downvotes every time

Comment: @Clive - but i tell you, please don't laugh at my poor coding standard, and down-vote with my sample code because of my poor knowledge.

Comment: @user3350885 Lack of knowledge is never a reason to downvote in my opinion, just (apparent) lack of effort :)

Comment: @Clive - I know we are all in the learning process, and you would have come up from a developer to an expert level. so don't laugh at my code when I post the next time. ;)